# Re-rendering throws off my logic when using react-dnd

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-dnd

Right now I'm building a DnD game.

It looks like this:
[image: photo]

When I drop an answer over a slot, the answer should be in that exact place, so the order matters.

My approach kind of works, but not perfectly.

So, in the parent component I have two arrays which store the slots' content and the answers' content.

The problem is easy to understand, you don't have to look at the code in-depth, just mostly follow my text :)

```
import DraggableGameAnswers from './DraggableGameAnswers';

import DraggableGameSlots from './DraggableGameSlots';

import { DndProvider } from 'react-dnd';
import { HTML5Backend } from 'react-dnd-html5-backend';
import { useState } from 'react';

type DraggableGameStartProps = {
    gameImages: Array<string>,
    gameAnswers: Array<string>,
    numberOfGameAnswers?: number,
    typeOfAnswers: string,
    correctAnswer: string
}

function DraggableGameStart(props: DraggableGameStartProps) {
    const [slots, setSlots] = useState<string[]>(["", "", "", ""]);
    const [answers, setAnswers] = useState<string[]>(props.gameAnswers);

    return (
        <DndProvider backend={HTML5Backend}>
            <div className="draggable-game-content">
                <div className="draggable-game">
                    <DraggableGameSlots
                    answers={answers}
                    slots={slots}
                    setAnswers={setAnswers}
                    setSlots={setSlots}
                    numberOfAnswers={4}
                    slotFor={props.typeOfAnswers}
                    />
                    <DraggableGameAnswers
                        gameAnswers={answers}
                        numberOfGameAnswers={props.numberOfGameAnswers}
                        typeOfAnswers={props.typeOfAnswers}
                    />
                </div>
            </div>
        </DndProvider>
    );
}

export default DraggableGameStart;
```

DraggableGameSlots is then a container, which loops through props.slots and renders each slot.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import DraggableGameSlot from "./DraggableGameSlot";

type DraggableGameSlotsProps = {
    answers: string[],
    slots: string[],
    setAnswers: any,
    setSlots: any,
    numberOfAnswers: number,
    slotFor: string
}

function DraggableGameSlots(props: DraggableGameSlotsProps) {    
    return (
        <div className="draggable-game-slots">
            {
                props.slots.map((val, index) => (
                    <DraggableGameSlot
                        index={index}
                        typeOf={props.slotFor === "text" ? "text" : "image"}
                        key={index}
                        answers={props.answers}
                        slots={props.slots}
                        setAnswers={props.setAnswers}
                        setSlots={props.setSlots}
                        toDisplay={val === "" ? "Drop here" : val}
                    />
                ))
            }
        </div>
    );
}

export default DraggableGameSlots;
```

In DraggableGameSlot I make my slots a drop target. When I drop an element, I iterate through the slots, and when I reach that element's position in the array, I modify it with the answer.

Until now everything works fine, as expected, I just wrote this for context.

E.g. if the drop target's index is 2, I modify the 3rd position in the slots array. (slots[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nYd2K.png) for 0-index based)

```
import { useEffect } from 'react';
import { useDrop } from 'react-dnd';
import './css/DraggableGameSlot.css';
import DraggableGameImage from './DraggableGameImage';

type DraggableGameSlotProps = {
    index: number,
    typeOf: string,
    answers: string[],
    slots: string[],
    setAnswers: any,
    setSlots: any,
    toDisplay: string
}

function DraggableGameSlot(props: DraggableGameSlotProps) {
    const [{ isOver }, drop] = useDrop(() => ({
        accept: "image",
        drop(item: { id: string, toDisplay: string }) {
            props.setAnswers(props.answers.filter((val, index) => index !== parseInt(item.id)));
            props.setSlots(props.slots.map((val, index) => {
                if (props.index === index) {
                    console.log("ITEM " + item.toDisplay);
                    return item.toDisplay;
                }
                return val;
            }));
        },
        collect: (monitor) => ({
            isOver: !!monitor.isOver(),
        })
    }), [props.slots])

    // useEffect(() => console.log("answers " +props.answers), [props.answers]);
    // useEffect(() => console.log("slots " + props.slots), [props.slots]);

    const dragClass: string = isOver ? "is-dragged-on" : "";

    return (
        <>
        {(props.typeOf === "image" && props.toDisplay !== "Drop here") ? 
        <>
        <span>da</span>
        <DraggableGameImage 
        className={`game-answers-image ${dragClass}`}
        imgSrc={props.toDisplay}
        imgAlt={"test"}
        dndRef={drop}
        />
        </>
        :
        <div className={`draggable-game-slot draggable-game-slot-for-${props.typeOf} ${dragClass}`} ref={drop}>
                <span>{props.toDisplay}</span>
        </div> 
        }
        </>
    )
}

export default DraggableGameSlot;
```

The problem comes with the logic in DraggableGameAnswer.

First, the container, DraggableGameAnswer. Using the loop, I pass that "type" (it is important because from there the error happens)

DraggableGameAnswers.tsx

```
import './css/DraggableGameAnswers.css';
import GameNext from '../GameComponents/GameNext';
import DraggableGameAnswer from './DraggableGameAnswer';
import { useEffect } from 'react';

type DraggableGameAnswersProps = {
    gameAnswers: Array<string>,
    numberOfGameAnswers?: number,
    typeOfAnswers: string
}

function DraggableGameAnswers(props: DraggableGameAnswersProps) {      
    let toDisplay: Array<string>;
    if(props.numberOfGameAnswers !== undefined)
    {
        toDisplay = props.gameAnswers.slice(props.numberOfGameAnswers);
    }
    else
    {
        toDisplay = props.gameAnswers;
    }
    useEffect(() => console.log(toDisplay));
    
    return (
        <div className="draggable-game-answers">
            {
            toDisplay.map((val, index) => (
            <DraggableGameAnswer
            key={index}
            answer={val} 
            typeOfAnswer={props.typeOfAnswers}
            type={`answer${index}`}
            />
            ))}
            <GameNext className="draggable-game-verify" buttonText="Verify"/>
        </div>
    );
}

export default DraggableGameAnswers;
```

In DraggableGameAnswer, I render the draggable answer:

```
import DraggableGameImage from "./DraggableGameImage";
import "./css/DraggableGameAnswer.css";
import { useDrag } from "react-dnd";
import { ItemTypes } from "./Constants";

type DraggableGameAnswerProps = {
    answer: string,
    typeOfAnswer: string,
    type: string
}

function DraggableGameAnswer(props: DraggableGameAnswerProps) {
    const [{ isDragging }, drag] = useDrag(() => ({
        type: "image",
        item: { id: ItemTypes[props.type],
        toDisplay: props.answer,
        typeOfAnswer: props.typeOfAnswer },
        collect: (monitor) => ({
            isDragging: !!monitor.isDragging(),
        })
    }))

    return (
        <>
            {props.typeOfAnswer === "image" ?
                <DraggableGameImage
                    className="draggable-game-image-answer"
                    imgSrc={props.answer}
                    imgAlt="test"
                    dndRef={drag}
                /> :
                <div className="draggable-game-text-answer" ref={drag}>
                    {props.answer}
                </div>
            }
        </>
    );
}

export default DraggableGameAnswer;
```

Constants.tsx (for ItemTypes)

```
export const ItemTypes: Record<string, any> = {
    answer0: '0',
    answer1: '1',
    answer2: '2',
    answer3: '3'
}
```

Okay, now let me explain what's happening.

The error starts because of the logic in DraggableGameAnswers container - I set the type using the index for the loop.

Everything works fine at the beginning. Then, let's say, I move answer3 in in the 4th box. It looks like this now:
[image: photo3]

It is working fine until now.

But now, the components have re-rendered, the map runs again, but the array is shorter with 1 and answer1's type will be answer1, answer2's type will be answer2, and answer4's type will be answer3.

So, when I drag answer4 over any box, I will get another answer3, like this:
[image: photo4]

How can I avoid this behavior and still get answer4 in this situation? I'm looking for a react-style way, better than my idea that I'll describe below.

So, here is how I delete an answer from the answers array:

```
props.setAnswers(props.answers.filter((val, index) => index !== parseInt(item.id)));
```

I can just set the deleted's answer position to NULL, to keep my array length for that index, and when I render the answers if the value is NULL, just skip it.

Comment: why you filtering answers? the filter questions as well

Comment: @AshishKamble I'm deleting the dragged answer from the list of answers to be rendered with that statement